# not able to create database through android app

Tags: android, database

I have make an android app in which i have made an registration activity. After submitting data through application. My database hasn't  create please help me.

in  other words

I simply make an app in which i have add registration activity and attach local database to create an user table. But i am not able to do this. check out my code

Here is my code ....

```html
package com.thechamp.resgimyapplication;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name, email, phone, add, password;
    Button sign;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("userdata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table if not exists sign(name varchar, email varchar, password varchar, address varchar, phone varchar)");
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        sign = findViewById(R.id.sign);
        sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String names = name.getText().toString();
                String emails = email.getText().toString();
                String passwords = password.getText().toString();
                String adds = add.getText().toString();
                String phones = phone.getText().toString();

                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("insert into sign values ('"+names+"', '"+emails+"','"+passwords+"', '"+adds+"', '"+phones+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sucessfully SignUp",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: @sasikumar The table is not being made

Comment: You need to specify the length of a varchar field.  However this should not stop the database being created.  Can you look at the logs from running your application and paste any errors printed there?

Comment: @SimonCrane Their is no error. If i run same project on Other's laptop's Android stuido, then my project works fine and if i run my project on my pc's Android studio. then it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use and learn the "room" library, it is easier, faster and more efficient